# Why Was This App Rejected?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

Apple rejected this app, and even provided a long explanation in the Resolution Center, but I am not certain why.  Could someone help me translate?

> 2.23
>
> We found that your app does not follow the iOS Data Storage
>   Guidelines, which is required per the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> In particular, we found that on launch and/or content download, your
>   app stores downloaded media (MP3 files). To check how much data your
>   app is storing:
>
> - Install and launch your app
> - Go to Settings > iCloud > Storage & Backup > Manage Storage
> - If necessary, tap "Show all apps"
> - Check your app's storage
>
> The iOS Data Storage Guidelines indicate that only content that the
>   user creates using your app, e.g., documents, new files, edits, etc.,
>   may be stored in the /Documents directory - and backed up by iCloud.
>
> Temporary files used by your app should only be stored in the /tmp
>   directory; please remember to delete the files stored in this location
>   when the user exits the app.
>
> Data that can be recreated but must persist for proper functioning of
>   your app - or because customers expect it to be available for offline
>   use - should be marked with the "do not back up" attribute. For NSURL
>   objects, add the NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey attribute to prevent the
>   corresponding file from being backed up. For CFURLRef objects, use the
>   corresponding kCFURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey attribute.
>
> For more information, please see Technical Q&A 1719: How do I prevent
>   files from being backed up to iCloud and iTunes?.
>
> It is necessary to revise your app to meet the requirements of the iOS
>   Data Storage Guidelines. For discrete code-level questions, you may
>   wish to consult with Apple Developer Technical Support. Please be sure
>   to:
>
> - include the complete details of your rejection issues
> - prepare any symbolicated crash logs, screenshots, and steps to reproduce the issues for when the DTS engineer follows up.
>
> For information on how to symbolicate and read a crash log, please see
>   Tech Note TN2151 Understanding and Analyzing iPhone OS Application
>   Crash Reports.
>
> If you have difficulty reproducing this issue, please try testing the
>   workflow as described in
>   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1764/Testing Workflow
>   with Xcode's Archive feature".

Comment: What do you not understand?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> The iOS Data Storage Guidelines indicate that only content that the user creates using your app, e.g., documents, new files, edits, etc., may be stored in the /Documents directory - and backed up by iCloud.
>
> Temporary files used by your app should only be stored in the /tmp directory; please remember to delete the files stored in this location when the user exits the app.
>
> Data that can be recreated but must persist for proper functioning of your app - or because customers expect it to be available for offline use - should be marked with the "do not back up" attribute. For NSURL objects, add the NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey attribute to prevent the corresponding file from being backed up. For CFURLRef objects, use the corresponding kCFURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey attribute.

That right there tells you exactly what they think the problem is. Apparently, you're storing data that isn't created by the user themselves in a location that iCloud backs up, without telling iCloud to not back it up. (iCloud is only supposed to back up user-created data.)

Comment: seems pretty straight forward to me

Comment: Does an mp3 that the user tells the app to download to their phone not count as user created data?

Comment: No, because the MP3 wasn't created by the app.  It was created by the artist (or whoever recorded the music into MP3 format); your app just pulled it from the Internet.

Comment: Had never heard of this before and I have two other apps submitted in the last month that passed review that both do the exact same thing.  So, instead of saving files to the Documents directory (something developers were always told to do), we now have to store it in a Caches directory?  Will those get replaced with an update to the app?

Comment: @CodaFi I was not using that as an argument that it should have been approved.  I mentioned it because I had very recently had apps approved that do this.  It is not flawed logic to assume that something that met guidelines a week ago would meet it today.  We shouldn't expect guidelines to change that much in a short amount of time.

Comment: You'd be surprised at how fast and how much the guidelines changed.  I mean, it was only months ago that apple disallowed interpreted code (flash, python, etc.).  And it's not a matter of the guidelines changing so much as that your apps slipped by and they finally caught you.

Comment: @CodaFi it is a matter of guidelines changing.  Even the moderators at MacRumors didn't know about this change.  Until very recently, devs were always instructed to put downloaded items in the Documents Directory

Comment: >1. Only documents and other data that is user-generated, or that cannot otherwise be recreated by your application, should be stored in the <Application_Home>/Documents directory and will be automatically backed up by iCloud. (From the [iDSG](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/))

Comment: As mentioned before.  THIS IS A RECENT CHANGE!  Before, all apps were to store in NSDocumentsDirectory.  End of story.

Comment: @CodaFi Check this out from MacForums.


I've did some research and went through the guidelines, before they wanted you to copy it to NSDOcumentsDirectory, but that gets backupped to iCloud, to avoid syncing several gigs of people downloading PDF's etc in their app, Apple is rejecting applications who do "unnessecary" downloads to the Documents folder, in other meanings, if you can easily redownload it, or store it somewhere else, like the library.

Comment: That change was communicated on September 9th, 2011, see: https://developer.apple.com/news/ and search for "iCloud", also send out to all developers via email. You might want to add the attribute "Do Not Backup" for e.g. a subfolder in documents where you can put your mp3 files and you'll be fine. @CodaFi is helping you and what he said is right. No need for big letters.

Comment: @Kerni I am a developer.  I never received an email.  I checked spam and nothing there from Apple since last August.  I don't make a habit of logging on to the developer news and searching for iCloud every day to see if they snuck in recent changes.

Comment: @user717452: you may then want to subscribe to the RSS feed of that developers news page so you will get future changes at least :)

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use the instructions [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011342) and this only support iOS5.0.1, 5.1 or later, for iOS 5.0, you need to store the data in the caches, that means the data would lose due to the update.