# App Rejected for "resembles Pokemon"

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

This is the message from apple:

> "Your app or its metadata appears to contain misleading content.
>
> Specifically, your app includes content that resembles Pokémon.
>
> Please see attached screenshots for details.
>
> You will experience a delayed review process if you deliberately
>   disregard the App Store Review Guidelines, ignore previous rejection
>   feedback in future app submissions, or use your app to mislead or
>   deceive users."

My app is a Pokdex and is supposed to contain images of Pokemon.
How come there are other Pokedex apps in the app store with Pokemon images?
What should I do for this to get approved and how do I get approval from the copyright owners?

Comment: How are we supposed to know why Apple rejected your app?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking us to guess at why a 3rd party rejected an app.

Comment: @BryanOakley how come this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759779/why-was-this-app-rejected?rq=1 wasn't closed? How should I format my question for this to be valid?

Comment: I have no idea. Though if I were to guess, I would say it wasn't closed because it is more about a very specific technical aspect of the program whereas your question is more about an app that "resembles" another app. "resembles" is highly subjective.  It's very difficult for us to guess why apple thinks that your app resembles another app, particularly when we have absolutely no idea what your app looks like. You've provided no screenshots so for all we know your app could look precisely like an existing pokemon game, or it could look like a fart game.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Stack Overflow isn't the best place to discuss App Store rejections of this nature, but I'm probably in a good position to give some insight on this. :)

I shipped a Pokédex app on the App Store named iPokédex back in 2011, using official art assets and pictures from Bulbapedia. Within a month, I received an email from Apple stating that the Pokémon Company International had filed a copyright claim against my app and asked me to sort it out with them.

I emailed Pokémon's General Counsel, and they replied with a very detailed email saying that the Pokémon Company does not allow unlicensed third party Pokémon apps on the App Store and asked me to take it down. I (borderline tearfully) took it down at the end of that week.

This year, I was lucky enough to get a chance to visit Pokémon HQ up in Seattle and met that counsel directly. I put the question to them again directly asking if there was *ANY* way a third party indie could get licensing permission for a Pokémon app, and they flat out said no. They operate on a corporate scale much larger than that in which an indie can participate.

In the past, Apple has been very lax when it comes to copyright infringing apps. They'd allow anything on the App Store, and only when the original party filed a suit, they'd start acting on it.

That seems to have changed in recent times, probably now that Pokémon GO, an officially licensed app, is on the App Store and the popularity of Pokémon on the store has skyrocketed as a result.

I talked to one of the App Store review team members at WWDC this year, and they said they're starting to be a bit more proactive about copyright. If you're making an app about a popular intellectual property, they might require you to supply documentation stating that you have official permission to use that property. Pokémon GO probably ensured that Apple scrutinizes most Pokémon app submissions in that way now.

Any existing Pokémon apps on the App Store might have avoided that scrutiny initially, but they'll be at risk of it happening to them every time they do an app update now.

There's no easy way to say this, but it's highly unlikely you'll get official approval from Pokémon, and without it, Apple won't let you publish your Pokédex app. The counsel assured me that any and all existing Pokédex apps in the App Store will eventually get the same copyright claim that I did in 2011.

I'm sorry. If it's any consolation, you're not the first Pokémon fan to which this has happened.

Comment: From many years of listening to TiM talk about this, can confirm his feelings and opinions are likely accurate.  Sorry :(

Comment: :( this just broke my heart. anyway, thanks TiM

Comment: @TrentLloyd Hahaha thanks for the mental support Trent! XD IIRC, it was a Friday evening when we were both setting up for an RFLAN when I went ahead and pulled the app from the App Store from my iPhone. Good times. 

Comment: @binsnoel Thanks man! I'm glad I was able to help, but I'm sorry I couldn't bring better news. Personally, a lot of those Pokémon apps on the App Store are really old now, so I was actually wondering if Apple/Pokémon were actually doing anything about it. Looks like they are. Hopefully you can still put that code to good use somewhere. :)

Comment: @binsnoel Another Pokémon app developer contacted me on Twitter last night and said they got the same rejection notice, but they were able to get it approved when they replied to Apple and explained their app. I won't make any recommendations on what you should do. Just letting you know. :)

Comment: @TiM I tried resubmitting the app but got rejected again for the same reason. I just blurred out the images of Pokemon on the screenshots. haha 
Did they, by any chance reveal how they explained their app? I just want to try all the options to get this to the app store before i give up. haha Thanks Tim :)